# How to get the href value from the xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2

Below is my element location, i need to find the id from this link.

```
<a href="bnf_view.aspx?QBnfId=BGOOE00003" class="case-hdr" xpath="1">Dean Ambrose</a>
```

Expecting this output-BGOOE00003

```
WebElement Clientlist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='MnClient']"));
Clientlist.click();

WebElement Clientclick = driver.findElement(By
   .xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainContent_ctl00_RadGridList_ctl00__0']/td[2]/a"));
Clientclick.click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
String attribute = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='case-hdr']")).getText();
//WebElement attribute= driver.findElement(Clienthover);

//String attribute = Clienthover.getAttribute("href");
System.out.println(attribute);
```

Comment: What it's printing?
Can you please post output that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the the id of the link that you have mentioned. Please try modified code below.

```
WebElement Clientlist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='MnClient']"));
Clientlist.click();

WebElement Clientclick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainContent_ctl00_RadGridList_ctl00__0']/td[2]/a"));
Clientclick.click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
String attribute = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='case-hdr']"))
//WebElement attribute= driver.findElement(Clienthover);

attribute.getAttribute("id");
System.out.println(attribute);
```

If you want `href` then you can try below code

```
String attribute = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='case-hdr']"))
//WebElement attribute= driver.findElement(Clienthover);

attribute.getAttribute("href");
System.out.println(attribute);
```

Comment: attribute.getAttribute("href")- this will print the whole URL in the output. I have tried this already. But I wanted the output only few portion of the URL. That is: BGOOE00003.

Comment: If the URL that your trying to get does not keep on changing. Maybe you can extract the part that you want